# Clickable image with discord embed?

Tags: python, embed, discord

So is it possible to set a link to the big image you can see below

[image: Test]

What do I need to change in this code?
`embed.set_image(url="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41j-vKWKFfL._SL250_.jpg")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to url-link an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can with discohook.org, add an embed then click image and add the image url, to get the url post the image you want to discord then click it and then copy the url and paste it into discohook image embed